# How can I print array of object into my table using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I just want to print array which I get from the firebase. You can see in the image the array data.

In which I convert json object data into the array easily, but I cannot print the array data in table.
If I run console.log command on  tag that time it print the console data, but not print the array value that I get from the firebase or you can say fetch from the firebase.
I want to print these data in table.

[image]

```html
class Contact extends React.Component {
          constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
              arr: [],
              inner_key:[],
              Address:'',
              printabledata:[],
              singledata:{}
            };
            self = this;
              this.printAllRecord = this.printAllRecord.bind(this);
            
          }

          componentWillMount() {  
          var formdata2 = firebase.database().ref("vishal-aaede/");
            formdata2.on("value", function (snap) {
                data = snap.val();
                self.setState({arr: data});
            });
          }

          componentDidUpdate(){
          var data=this.state.arr,
          headerArray=[];
          for (var key in data){
          headerArray.push(key);
          }console.log(headerArray);

           headerArray.forEach(function(val){
            self.printAllRecord(data[val])
            console.log(data[val].Name);
           } );
           self.state.singledata=data[headerArray[0]]
               ;       
          }
          printAllRecord(param,index){         
        self.state.printabledata.push(<tr>
        <td>{param.Name}</td>
        <td>{param.Round}</td>
        <td>{param.Email}</td>
        <td>{param.Date}</td>
        <td>{param.Phone}</td>
        <td>{param.Address}</td>
        <td>{param.Fresher}</td>
        <td>{param.Time}</td>
        </tr>);     
      }
           render() {
               return (
                 <div>
                   <h2>Candidate RECORD Coming Soon!!!!</h2>
                   <p>Write Filter Code here
                   </p>
                   <div>
                      <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-2"></div>
                        <div className="col-sm-8">
                          <div className = "container-fluid table-responsive">            
                            <table className = "table table-bordered">
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                 <th>Name</th>
                                 <th>Interview Round</th>
                                 <th>Email</th>
                                 <th>Date</th>
                                 <th>Phone Number</th>
                                 <th>Address</th>
                                 <th>Gender</th>  
                                 <th>Experience</th>
                                 <th>Time</th>
                               </tr>
                              </thead>
                             <tbody>
                              {this.state.printabledata}
                              
                             </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-2"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
               )
             }
            }
```

Comment: You shouldnt manipulate `state` directly,use `this.setState`,check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state).

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating elements with the wrong approach. If you want to `loop` through `array` elements then you should use `array.map` methods. You can find some reference here for how we [print a list of elements in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: Thank you arun, can you plz update this code it very helpful if you do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using map

```
this.state.data.map(function(key,map) {
    <table>
        <tr></tr>
        <td>{map.name}</td?
        ....whole code
    </table>
})
```

Comment: Paste inside curly braces or you can make a variable like const table=//code

And then use it inside div tag as
<div>
<table/>
</div>